# Where is my solution wrong for this combinatorics problem?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The question is:

> How many ways can you arrange six $X$s in the given figure so that each row has at least one $X$?

[image]

(Image taken from the same question from Math Exchange.)

My solution: To have $3$ $X$s in $3$ rows, there are $2 \cdot  4 \cdot 2$ ways to place them. Now there remain $5$ places more and we have $3$ $X$s remaining. So to fill the remaining places, there are $C^5_3$ ways. So total number of ways $= 16 \cdot 10 = 160$. But the answer is $26$. Where am I wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify. So you are supposed to put the 'X's inside of the squares and each square can only contain a single 'X' and the 'X's all look the same??

Comment: There are $8$ cells, so $6$ will have X's and $2$ will be blank. There are $\binom82=28$ ways to place the $2$ blanks. But we don't want a whole row of blanks, i.e., we can't have both blanks on the top row or the bottom row. That rules out $2$ of the $28$ configurations. The final answer is $28-2=26.$

Comment: @Ram Isn't this a R.D. Sharma (JEE Maths) question? Just brought back old memories :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are overcounting the arrangements. For example, by choosing three $X$s in the three rows  and then filling the remaining places with three $x$s, we consider the following equivalent arrangements as different

```
 Xo    Xo    Xo    Xo
Xxxx  xXxx  xxXx  xxxX 
 Xo    Xo    Xo    Xo
```

Note that we have $\binom{8}{6}$ ways to place six $X$s in the eight cells. From this number we subtract $2$, the ways to have a row empty (the first and the third):
$$\binom{8}{6}-2=\frac{8\cdot 7}{2}-2=28-2=26.$$

Comment: This answer would be better if you gave a more detailed explanation of why the OP's solution is wrong, rather than simply giving your own solution.

Comment: @jwg Is it better now?

Answer (score 11):

The problem with your solution is that you count a lot of the combinations twice. For instance, if we first add

```
 xo
xooo
 xo
```

and then add the rest of the three to form

```
 xo
xxxx
 xo
```

it is the same as starting with

```
 xo
ooxo
 xo
```

and then adding the rest of the x to form

```
 xo
xxxx
 xo
```

Now instead of doing the difficult thing and removing the duplicates of your solution do it like this: Just place all x. This can be done in $8 \choose 6$ ways. However when we fill the top row and the middle row, or the bottom row and the middle row, there is one row without an x. Thus we have to subtract $2$. Hence the solution is  ${8 \choose 6 } - 2 = 26$.